# generalisation of singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, singular-values

Let's say I have a vector $$f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 
f_1(x) \\
f_2(x) \\
\vdots \\
f_n(x) 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n $$
consisting of continuous functions $f_i, i = 1,..., n$ and $x \in [0, 1]$. If you look at the space $$\mbox{span} \{ f(x) | x \in [0,1] \}$$ then this has dimension $n$ except if the ratio between 2 different $f_i(x) $stays the same or if there are $f_i(x)$ which are zero.

Discretize now the interval $[0,1]$ uniformly into $x_i, i = 1, ..., m$ with $m$ big enough and define now $F := [f(x_1), ..., f(x_m)]$, If you calculate a singular value decomposition of this $F$, this allows you to check if $F$ can be well approximated by a lower-dimensional subspace (by checking the singular values). If $m$ is big enough, this can tell you if $\mbox{span} \{ f(x) | x \in [0,1] \}$ can be well approximated by a low dimensional subspace.

I was wondering if given the function $f$ there is a method to immediately check if this space can be approximated by a low-dimensional subspace, without doing the discretisation and calculating an svd.

many thanks

Comment: The singular values of $F$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $FF^T$, whose $(i,j)$th entry is $\sum_k f_i(x_k)f_j(x_k)$. Similarly, in the continuous case you can define the matrix whose entries are $\langle f_i,f_j\rangle = \int_x f_i(x)f_j(x)$ and compute the square roots of its eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I was looking for.